# Mat-tab-group go directly on second tab using angular

Tags: angular, tabs

I'm trying to use  in my component like this :

```
        <mat-tab-group id="stickyTabs" dynamicHeight="false" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab" #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event);">
            <mat-tab *ngIf="condition" label="label1">
                <ng-template matTabContent >
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <comp1></comp1>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="label2">
                <ng-template matTabContent>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <comp2></comp2>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
```

But when I go on my page, I go directly on the second tab. I suppose that the `ngIf` is the problem so, y question is, can I put a tab in first place with a `ngIf` condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if the condition is initially true. I guess this isn't the case in your situation. Maybe you can solve this by making the mat-tab-group conditionally as well?

Comment: Thank's mate ! Initialize the condition works fine !